# SQL/HIVE How to combine two queries with different where statements into one query?

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following query where I’m trying to count all the instances where columnA is either Y or N for data_set “1234”.

```
select
data_set as DATA_SET,
sum(case when columnA <> '' and columnA = ‘Y’ then 1 else 0 end) as YES,
sum(case when columnA <> '' and columnA = ’N’ then 1 else 0 end) as NO
from myTable1
where data_set = 1234
group by data_set;
```

It returns:

```
data_set       | YES           | NO
1531587375     | 6,287,732     | 54,228,649
```

Now, what I would like to now how to do is how do I look for TWO different data_set (ds1=1234, ds2=4321) in the same query and return something like:

```
Column |  ds1.count | ds2.count
Y      |  134,543   | 153,678
N      |  5,080     | 989,820
```

Comment: How does the multiple data_sets relate to your yes/no calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, the following worked for me:

```
select
columnA,
sum(case when columnA <> '' and data_set = 1234 then 1 else 0 end) as PREVIOUS_COUNT,
sum(case when columnA <> '' and data_set = 4321 then 1 else 0 end) as CURRENT_COUNT
from myTable1
where data_set in (1234, 4321)
group by columnA
order by columnA ASC;
```